# Caching a function in C++

Tags: c++

I am familiar with basic C++ only. So, not really sure if I am given a function say `f(a, b)` and I need to build a cache wrapper on top of it, how will I do it? Cache wrapper will return results from cache if they exist otherwise put it there as a fresh  entry.

In Javascript I know that we can do something of sort::

```js
function cached(f) {
    const cache = new Map();
    return function(...args) {
        const cacheKey = args.join(',');
        if (!cache.has(cacheKey)) {
            const value = f(...args);
            cache.set(cacheKey, value);
        }

        return cache.get(cacheKey);
    }
}
```

So, a few things I need to figure out...

1. How can I pass function to another function in C++ or emulate something similar.
2. Spread operator `...args` expands the args to be accessible as index based entries. Don't know the C++ equivalent of the same.
3. `join` operation forms a string from args array directly - `const cacheKey = args.join(',');`

I am just putting one-to-one mapping here. I'm sure there might not be direct equivalents in C++. Please suggest the best way to build cache wrapper to cache function results!

Comment: Hint: [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: You might try googling for "C++ memoization" and "C++ dynamic programming". I haven't checked but I expect good results.

Comment: Guys, I know about map `unordered_map` or `map` in C++.  Am I missing something about the difficulty part here? function `f` is an external API whose code is not available to me to modify. So I have to create a wrapper and not just use map and memo it. Difficulty is there.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pass function to another function in C++ or emulate something similar.

There are several options, including passing function pointers, function objects, etc.

> Spread operator `...args` expands the args to be accessible as index based entries. Don't know the C++ equivalent of the same.

Variadic arguments, forwarding, etc. is available in C++ too, with a similar syntax.

> `join` operation forms a string from args array directly - `const cacheKey = args.join(',');`

There is no function to do that in the standard, but one is fairly easy to come up with. There is also the algorithms header that provides you with a generic version of that, and also the new C++20 ranges for another take on it.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer with examples on these points?

Comment: @kushalvm take a look at [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as an easy solution to passing a function around.

Comment: @kushalvm I am afraid that is too broad for StackOverflow and would be repeating what many books, articles and even other questions talk about. Please search for the terms to learn more.

Comment: Ummm... wondering how writing a cached function could be broad?

Comment: @kushalvm You asked for "*examples on these points*". That is what is broad. This answers gives you the names of many concepts you will have to learn to write the wrapper function. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.